# Render ONLY the Reflection

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

So I have these balls flying like meteors from behind an Earth.
Each ball arrives at it's location and the next one comes out.

Since I'm rendering the balls separately ([Programmatic Sequence Rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72734/how-to-programatically-render-multiple-times-with-different-materials-each?noredirect=1#comment127760_72734) ), I had to get rid of the Glossy effect showing the particle effect of ball 2 reflected on the glossy texture of ball 1 (etc....).

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to render ONLY that glossy reflection parts, that appear in the images above?

Comment: Not sure what is the problem without screenshots, but try rendering Glossy Direct and Glossy Indirect render passes; they contain information about reflections (enable them in Render Layers tab > Passes rollout).

Comment: There, added images.

Can I render ONLY those passes? How?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27934/how-can-i-reflect-a-transparent-background/45625#45625

Comment: To render only one pass enable it in Render Layers tab > Passes rollout and uncheck everything else. Although this might not be the solution as reflections can conflict because of separate rendering of those balls.